# how to cancel the timer task before it is executed when a button is clicked

Tags: java, android, timer

i want to know how to cancel a timer task when the button is clicked.. i am doing a simple math game, in that i have assigned a timertask for changing the text of a textview and i want to cancel it when a button is clicked.But i am getting out of the application when i am doing this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button b1, b2,b3;
ImageView i, i2, i3;
TextView t1, t2, t3,t4;
String s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;
LinearLayout pooku;
Button bk;
int q, m, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, n[];
Random r1 = new Random();
Random r0 = new Random();
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable r;
Timer t = new Timer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    pooku = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pooka);
    i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    t4= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);

    imp();

}

public TimerTask malli(){
 return new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

            t4.setText("times up");

            t4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            });
    }
};
}

public void imp() {

    t.schedule(malli(), 3000);



    r2 = r1.nextInt(9) + 1;
    r3 = r1.nextInt(9) + 1;
    r4 = r2 + r3;
    r5 = r2 - r3;
    r6 = r2 * r3;

    n = new int[] { r4, r5, r6 };

    doit();
    while (r9 == r11 || r9 == r13 || r11 == r13) {
        doit();
    }
    s1 = Integer.toString(r2);
    s2 = Integer.toString(r3);
    s3 = Integer.toString(r9);
    s4 = Integer.toString(r11);
    s5 = Integer.toString(r13);
    t1.setText(s1);
    t2.setText(s2);
    b1.setText(s3);
    b2.setText(s4);
    b3.setText(s5);

    int[] images = { R.drawable.plus, R.drawable.minus, R.drawable.multiply };

    Random random = new Random();




    m = images[random.nextInt(images.length)];
    i.setImageResource(m);
    bk.setFocusable(true);
    bk.requestFocus();
    bk.requestFocusFromTouch();
}

public void doit() {
    r9 = 0;
    r11 = 0;
    r13 = 0;
    r8 = r1.nextInt(3) + 0;
    r9 = n[r8];
    r10 = r1.nextInt(3) + 0;
    r11 = n[r10];
    r12 = r1.nextInt(3) + 0;
    r13 = n[r12];
    int[] buttons = { R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3 };
    q = buttons[r0.nextInt(buttons.length)];
    bk = (Button) findViewById(q);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        click(r9, b1);

        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        click(r11, b2);
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        click(r13, b3);
        break;
    }
}

public void click(int k, Button b) {
    if (m == R.drawable.plus && k == r4 || m == R.drawable.minus && k == r5
            || m == R.drawable.multiply && k == r6) {

        t3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        t4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        this.t.cancel();
        imp();
        t4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    } else {
        t3.setText("FINISH");
        t3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b.setPressed(true);
        b1.setClickable(false);
        b2.setClickable(false);
        b3.setClickable(false);
        b.requestFocusFromTouch();

    }
  }
}
```

and logcat report is

```
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493): Process: com.example.emo2,  PID: 11493
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at  java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:561)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at  java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:459)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at   com.example.emo2.MainActivity.imp(MainActivity.java:74)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at   com.example.emo2.MainActivity.click(MainActivity.java:154)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at   com.example.emo2.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:135)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18442)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:82 7)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
04-04 16:47:47.681: E/AndroidRuntime(11493):    at   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what do you mean "out of the application" ?

Comment: it is crashing saying "unfortunately your application has stopped working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Put in your button's onClickListener():**

if (t != null)
    t.cancel();

**Code Example:**

```
final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourpay);

final Timer t =new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                money = (PPS+Reserve);
                Reserve = (money);
                t1.setText("$" + money); //Place your text data here

                // Removed the stopping condition/counter

            }
        }); 
    }
}, 1000, 1000); // Do you really want to wait 1 second before executing the timer's code?  If not, change the 1st "1000" to a "0"


final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button_id); // Replace with your button's id
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (t != null)
            t.cancel();
        }
});
```

Comment: but, i have another problem, if i press a button before 3 seconds, the task must be cancelled, but here even when i am pressing the button more than one time in 3 seconds , the text is changing after 3 seconds of the first click and then coming before 3 seconds as for the second click.... @sohail

Answer (score 0):

Just call `cancel` on `Timer` object in the first link of your button `onClick` method.

Comment: i did that thing... check in click();

Comment: try put it on first line of `onClick` before any logical checks

Comment: You must create a new `Timer` object each time, you can not re use the same one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flags for this.
In onclick you can set a flag to false and then implement a check in your timer to execute only when the flag is true/set.
Instead of `this.t.cancel` in your OnClick write `flag = false`

and then in your timer task

```
public TimerTask malli(){
    return new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    if(flag){
                        t4.setText("times up");
                        t4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     }
                }

            }); 
    }
};
```